# How can I stop cygwin bash from thinking every file is executable (and other related issues)?

Tags: windows, bash, permissions, cygwin

When I look at my files in a cygwin terminal, every file created by Windows or a Windows program has 770 permissions, which means they're executable by user & group. Files created by cygwin all have 674 permissions, which means they're executable by group but not owner (!) and also readable by other, which I don't want. In either case, if I use "ls -F", every file (except directories) is marked with an '*' to show it's executable. (Contrary to any of this, the cygwin documentation claims that files will be marked executable only under certain conditions, for example if the filename ends in ".sh" or ".exe".)

```
$ ls -lF
total 45
drwxrwx---+ 1 tom None     0 Nov 19 12:42 Debug/
-rwxrwx---+ 1 tom None  8347 Sep  3 14:28 lnk_delta.cmd*
drwxrwx---+ 1 tom None     0 Nov 18 14:25 notes/
-rwxrwx---+ 1 tom None 15565 Nov 19 12:44 main.c*
-rwxrwx---+ 1 tom None  5999 Nov 11 12:04 system_pre_init.c*
drwxrwx---+ 1 tom None     0 Oct 19 15:26 targetConfigs/
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 tom None     1 Nov 19 16:13 thisFileCreatedByCygwin*
```

Relatedly, when I create a file with cygwin, it's NTFS permissions include a group named NONE that also has read permission. If I create a directory with cygwin, it's NTFS permissions includegroups named NONE, CREATOR OWNER, and CREATOR GROUP.

This seems completely brain-damaged. Does anyone know how to fix it?
Thanks,
Tom

- cygwin version: cygwin64
- OS: Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit SP1
- disk format: NTFS
- cygwin login shell: /usr/bin/bash
- cygwin terminal: mintty.exe

Comment: I've been using cygwin on windows for years, and unfortunately it's just due to the fact that NTFS and cygwin don't play well. Windows has a very different idea on how permissions work from what the POSIX standards are.

Comment: That's just how drivers for vfat and ntfs work. Everything is rwx. A work around may be to shrink your windows drive, and create a linux-native drive.

Comment: I've been using it for some time, too, but sporadically. It's only now that I'm using it for a project that this stuff became obvious, irritating, and I think dangerous. Things I don't understand are (1) the cygwin documentations says that executable files are determined by file name and contents, (2) if other Windows programs can avoid marking everything publicly readable, why can't cygwin, (3) if other Windows programs can avoid giving files group ownership by 3 previously unused and ill-understood groups (NONE, CREATOR OWNER, CREATOR GROUP), why can't cygwin?

Comment: CREATOR OWNER and CREATOR GROUP are legitimate Windows security primitives, which affect inherited permissions.  I think they might be necessary here in order to make inherited permissions work as a UNIX programmer would expect them to.  (For when a Windows application creates a file in a Cygwin directory, perhaps?)  Or Cygwin might just be using them so that it can be sure it will read back the same permission mask that you set, despite the underlying ACL using a very different model (that's my guess for the purpose of NONE).  You should consider using a VM instead of Cygwin.